# C# WPF Applying Acrylic Blur to the Border

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-8.0

I want to give the Border Background an Acrylic Blur Effect, but I don't know how to do it. I tried BlurEffect, but the image became distorted, and it went outside the CornerRadius.

I was able to blur only the window using some methods, but the issue with the window is that the corners are not adopting the corner radius.

[image: desired result]